# Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

For my current project I am using React, Redux and Typescript. Here is my package.json dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.105",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.23",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "thunk": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.40",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",
    "mocha": "^5.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  }
```

I am not using babel to compile so please ignore the babel dependencies as I will remove them soon. I am using react-redux latest version but I am getting this error in console.

```
PropTypes.js?721c:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined
at eval (PropTypes.js?721c:3)
at Object../node_modules/react-redux/es/utils/PropTypes.js (bundle.js:970)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at eval (Provider.js?fa28:9)
at Object../node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js (bundle.js:850)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at eval (index.js?a7ec:1)
at Object../node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js (bundle.js:958)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at eval (index.tsx?d986:5)
```

I stumbled upon this issue https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/822 but this does not seem to solve my problem. You can see their code here https://unpkg.com/react-redux@5.0.7/es/utils/PropTypes.js

Update: I Got my mistake, I have changes the tsconfig.json 
`"module": "commonjs",`  to `"module": "es6",`

Comment: Try downgrading the react version to 15.6.2.
Refer: https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox-themr/issues/61

Comment: Would rather remove typescript